# Reverse rss parser output

Tags: rss, feedparser

I am trying to out put the next 5 tour dates for a band. 
Unfortunately as rss feeds output the latest feed item first I need to find a way to reverse the order. My php skills are limited so I would appreciate any help.

```
{exp:rss_parser url="http://acousti.co/feeds/artist/artist_name" 
                    cache_refresh="10"
                    limit="5"
                    }

    {feed_items}  


                  <li>{item_date format="%F %d %Y"}&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{item_link}">{item_description}</a>
                  </li>

                 {/feed_items}
                {/exp:rss_parser}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the inversion using [stash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash) lists.

This works in two stages.  First load a stash list with the content of your feed call.  Then recall the stash list with whatever ordering you care to specify.

Something like this:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="tour_dates"}

    {exp:rss_parser url="http://acousti.co/feeds/artist/artist_name" 
        cache_refresh="10"
        limit="5"
        }

        {feed_items}  
            {stash:item_date}{item_date}{/stash:item_date}
            {stash:item_link}{item_link}{/stash:item_link}
            {stash:item_description}{item_description}{/stash:item_description}
        {/feed_items}

    {/exp:rss_parser}

{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:get_list name="tour_dates" orderby="item_date" sort="desc"}

            <li>{item_date format="%F %d %Y"}&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{item_link}">{item_description}</a></li>

{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Of course you'll need to set the `orderby` tag appropriate to your source data.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your help - I installed Stash and tried your code but all that is being output is {item_date}  {item_description}.

Comment: Presumably this is within the `<li>...</li>` tags, and you only get one line output?  If so, that suggests in your code there is something wrong with the `{exp:stash:get_list}` call.  If so, check the opening and closing tags are entered correctly (`{` not `(` etc.).  If that is OK, can you post your actual code that is not working here so that others can have a look etc.